# ¿Se puede trazar un sólido de revolución en Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas

El problema nos dice:
"Calcular el volumen del sólido de revolución generado cuando la región acotada por la curva y=x^2, el eje x y las rectas x=1 y x=2 se gira alrededor del eje x".
hasta ahora su servidor ya ha logrado avances, se ha consegudo el volumen en unidades cuadradas con el código siguiente:

```
from sympy import integrate, Symbol
from sympy.plotting import plot
init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)
x = Symbol('x')
sol=integrate(x**4, (x,1,2))
sol*=3.1416
print(sol)
plot(x**4,(x,-5,5))
```

Muestra el gráfico muy bien de la curva y la respuesta correcta de volumen, pero ¿es posible graficar el sólido de revolución en Python 3 del área estudiada girada sobre el eje x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `plot_surface`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(-1, 2, 60)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 60)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)

X = U
Y1 = (U**2 + 1)*np.cos(V)
Z1 = (U**2 + 1)*np.sin(V)

Y2 = (U + 3)*np.cos(V)
Z2 = (U + 3)*np.sin(V)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y1, Z1, alpha=0.3, color='red', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y2, Z2, alpha=0.3, color='blue', rstride=6, cstride=12)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Mira la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464982/ploting-solid-of-revolution-in-python-3-matplotlib-maybe) en el sitio en inglés.

Espero te sirva.